# Magento 2 email not working

Tags: email, send-mail

```
$emails = ["'".$c_email."'", "'".$em."'"]; 
 $pdfFile = 'pub/pdf/13_rajeshnagappan2016@gmail.com.pdf';
 $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
 $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('enquiry_test_template')->setTemplateOptions(
     [
         'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
         'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
     ]
 )->setTemplateVars(
     [
         'message' => 'this is test with send mail',
     ]
 )->setFrom(
     [
         'email' => 'rajeshnagappan2017@gmail.com',
         'name' => 'Test'
     ]
 )->addTo($eml)
```

Comment: I used post email not working...

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Do you have an error message ?

Comment: Email sending right now. I added smtp extension.